# Load image into xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm a newbie with c# and XAML. So I need to create a button with a placeholder that says "click here to add image" and on click of this button, I need the image to be loaded into the button from the local directory. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button to your WPF with an EventHandler

```
<Button Width="150" Height="50" Click="Button_Click">click here to add image</Button>
```

the EventHandler in your code behind looks like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;

    btn.Content = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/logo.png")) };
}
```

add the image to your project

[image]

What you do not forget is that the image should be copied into the output folder
[image]

If you have any questions, I would like to help :)